# Examples of testing on-chain code

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, unit-test

There are extensive examples for the testing frameworks for contracts, ie off-chain code, for example as discussed in Lecture 8 of the plutus pioneer program https://youtu.be/zW3D2iM5uVg.

Its mentioned there that one thing not covered is the testing of validators directly, ie on-chain code.
Are there examples of this available?

Answer (score 2):

I raised this in a PPP QA. Lars said that he knows of two possible inroads to the problem:

- Write additional contracts with the sole purpose of testing.
- [cooked validators](https://github.com/tweag/plutus-libs/tree/main/cooked-validators) from Tweag